# Generate Rails 5 Channel using JavaScript asset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

The title pretty much describe my doubt. When I run on my project terminal `rails g channel conversion` it performs two actions:

```
create  app/channels/conversion_channel.rb
create  app/assets/javascripts/channels/conversion.coffee
```

The question is: How can I generate `conversion.js` instead of `conversion.coffee`?

Answer (score 1):

I think according [to this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/rails/generators/channel/channel_generator.rb#L16) this can't be done.

What about just renaming the file? :P

Comment: Yeap, I ended up just renaming the file and converting `coffee` to `javascript`. But this could be a nice feature for next releases...

Comment: You can create a pull request ;)